# Swift detecting collisions and setting enums

Tags: swift, enums, sprite-kit, collision

I'm trying to get my head around how detecting collision works when setting enums. I have several different nodes which I can detect collision on and have set up working however I have just winged it and don't understand how to correctly set it up.

```
enum ColliderType: UInt32{

    case ship = 1
    case object = 2
    case fuel = 4
    case alien = 8
    case torp = 16

}
```

Then I have each node set up as such:

```
mete.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
mete.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
mete.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue

alien.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.torp.rawValue
alien.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.alien.rawValue
alien.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.alien.rawValue

fuel.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue
fuel.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.fuel.rawValue
fuel.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.fuel.rawValue


ship.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
ship.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue
ship.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue

torpedoNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.alien.rawValue
torpedoNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.torp.rawValue
torpedoNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.alien.rawValue
```

Then to detect a collision between the ship and a mete the following code is what I'm using:

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue
```

A collision between the ship and fuel I use:

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.fuel.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.fuel.rawValue {
```

Then finally a collision between a torpedo and alien I use this code:

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.alien.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.torp.rawValue {
```

Everything works perfectly however I'm now trying to detect collision between the ship and alien and I can't work out how to go about doing this. I need to try understand the logic and clean this code up.

Comment: What you have as 'ColliderType' is just a physics category.  Setting a category to object's collisionBitMask and contactTestBitMask doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: There are plenty of answers here on SO that explain what you are interested in : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39064710, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31111039 etc...

Comment: Firstly get your head around the difference between **contacts** and **collisions** and start using the correct terminology - you don't detect collisions, you detect *contacts*.- http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sprite-kit/6261/sknode-collision/29294/difference-between-contacts-and-collisions#t=201703220900020381008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your code to be notified when ship contacts (not collides) either a mete, fuel or an alien, you should have:

```
ship.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue | ColliderType.fuel.rawValue | ColliderType.alien.rawValue
```

i.e. the contact Test bitmask is equal to `object` OR `fuel` OR `alien`.

Check out this simple Sprite-Kit project here on SO with contacts, collisions, touch events and a helper function (`checkPhysics()`) which will analyse your physics setup - this function can be dropped into any sprite-Kit project and called to show what contacts and collisions will occur between which physics bodies.

[Attack button in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599860/attack-button-in-spritekit/43605825#43605825)

**Additional info:**

It's worth remembering that unless you specify otherwise, everything collides with everything else and nothing contacts anything.

i.e. every node's `collisonBitMask` is set to all `1`s and its `contactTestbitMask` is set to all `0`s.

Contacts or collisions between nodeA and nodeB can be turned **off** using:

```
nodeA.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask &= ~nodeB.category
```

We logically AND nodeA's bitMask with the inverse (logical NOT, the ~ operator) of nodeB's category bitmask to 'turn off' that bit nodeA's bitMask.

Contacts or collisions between nodeA and nodeC can be turned **ON** at any point using:

```
nodeA.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask |= nodeC.category
```

We logically AND nodeA's bitMask with nodeC's category bitmask to 'turn on' that bit in nodeA's bitMask.

You can make sure that every shape 'bounces off' a screen edge as follows:

```
// Make sure everything collides with the screen edge
enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*") { node, _ in
    node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= self.edgeCategory  //Add edgeCategory to the collision bit mask
}
```

Comment: I've added  ColliderType.alien.rawValue to the ships contact bit mask. Would I then use if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.alien.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.alien.rawValue {? I've tried a few combinations but it usually messes up other contacts.

Comment: @Alex - yes, but if you want to avoid all those 'if..then' and the bodyA and bodyB things, look at this for a cleaner way to implement didBegin(contact:) - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sprite-kit/6261/sknode-collision/24159/alternative-didbegincontact#t=201703221158558453557